# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0 when loading a compiled dll

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I have a small dll compiled in Visual Studio written in C# (Class Library), which I want to use lateron in Matlab.
Currently my Target Framework is .Net 7.0 (but i have also tried different versions).
My minimal example of the included code is:

```
namespace newTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public double add(double x, double y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine, but when I want to load the file in Matlab it throws the following error:

> Error using newTestmatlab
> Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> Source: mscorlib

I know that there are similar questions and i have tried a lot of different solutions, but nothing worked so far (rebindings in app.config, include the System.Runtime in the Nuget packages, different .NET sdk versions, installed other .NET runtime versions)

Build Output:

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: newTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
Restoring packages for C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\newTest.csproj...
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\project.assets.json
Restored C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\newTest.csproj (in 11 ms).
NuGet package restore finished.
1>Build started 11/14/2023 11:07:42 AM.
1>Target CoreClean:
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\bin\Debug\net7.0\newTest.deps.json".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\bin\Debug\net7.0\newTest.dll".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\bin\Debug\net7.0\newTest.pdb".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\newTest.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\newTest.AssemblyInfoInputs.cache".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\newTest.AssemblyInfo.cs".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\newTest.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\newTest.dll".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\refint\newTest.dll".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\newTest.pdb".
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\ref\newTest.dll".
1>Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>Target CoreCompile:
1>  CompilerServer: server - server processed compilation - 54a7adbc-1a49-448f-9523-516a579659d8
1>Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
1>  Copying file from "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\newTest.dll" to "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\bin\Debug\net7.0\newTest.dll".
1>  Copying reference assembly from "obj\Debug\net7.0\refint\newTest.dll" to "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\ref\newTest.dll".
1>  newTest -> C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\bin\Debug\net7.0\newTest.dll
1>  Copying file from "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\obj\Debug\net7.0\newTest.pdb" to "C:\Users\42ggeissler\source\repos\newTest\bin\Debug\net7.0\newTest.pdb".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.78
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Rebuild started at 11:07 AM and took 01.203 seconds ==========
```

output of `dotnet --info` is:

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.403
 Commit:    142776d834

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.13
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       3f73a2f186

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Inspecting the dll with IlSpy:

```
// C:\Users\user\source\repos\newTest\bin\Debug\net7.0\newTest.dll
// newTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// Global type: <Module>
// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: v4.0.30319
// This assembly was compiled using the /deterministic option.
// Hash algorithm: SHA1
// Debug info: Loaded from portable PDB: C:\Users\user\source\repos\newTest\bin\Debug\net7.0\newTest.pdb

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(/*Could not decode attribute arguments.*/)]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET 7.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("newTest")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("newTest")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("newTest")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[module: RefSafetyRules(11)]
```

Anyone has an idea how to make it work? Do i have to something on the compilation or on the runtime side?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue until I started getting "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" after trying to run through the CLI. My issue was trying to use an x86 library with an x64 app. Double check your platform targets and make sure they are the same.